# Typescript: Empty output file when compiling

Tags: typescript

I compile the following code using the latest typescript compiler (1.4)

```
/// <reference path="typescript.d.ts" />

//import ts = require("typescript");
module cc {
console.log("Hello");
}
```

using the following compile args

```
node /TypeScript/built/local/tsc.js -m commonjs --noEmitOnError app.ts -out myApp.js
```

which compiles Ok and generates the "myApp.js" file.

When I uncomment the import line, I get no error on compiling, but it generates an empty (zero size) "myApp.js" and a file "app.js", even I have specified the --noEmitOnError switch.

This is a strip down example, in fact I specify multiple ".ts" files and I get no error on compiling, the empty "myApp.js" file and for each ".ts" file I specified, I get a ".js" file.

I am using node 0.10.30 on Windows 8.1

Comment: It's a local copy of /TypeScript/built/local/typescript.d.ts

Comment: I see this behavior as well.  What happens if you rename the `typescript.d.ts` file to `somethingelse.d.ts` and try to import that instead?  If it "works" by saying that it's not an external module, then you may have uncovered a bug that should be reported on GitHub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `--out` flag generally should not be used with external modules. Only code that is *not* part of an external module will be written to the specified output file. Files with a top-level `import` are an external module.

See also [modules documentation](https://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript), [this GitHub issue tracking](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17)